# Como hacer que los datos ingresados en un cuadro de texto se almacenen en una variable (Python,tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

estamos construyendo un proyecto que se encarga de resolver ecuaciones cuadraticas en Python, el problema que tenemos es que no encontramos la manera de hacer que los datos ingresados en un cuadro de texto, se almacenen en una variable, para asi luego utilizarla en la resolucion de la ecuacion.

Somos noobs llevamos 2 semanas aprendiendo Python, pero tenemos que presentar un proyecto en una semana, les agradeceriamos su ayuda...

Comment: Muestra lo que has intentado hasta el momento: lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Obtendrás la respuesta a tu pregunta haciendote esta pregunta: ¿Cómo obtener el contenido de un cuadro de texto? En este link te explican como obtener la totalidad de lo escrito por el usuario en el widget text: https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/python-tkinter/how-to-get-the-input-from-tkinter-text-box/. Una vez hecho esto, guardar el resultado del get en una variable es (como dicen en los doblajes de los dibujos animados) pan comido :D